# Clean install of ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on PC. Will not boot & bios shows no HDD only DVD?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I am new to this. I have just bought a new 1TB HDD and it is the only drive in my Desktop PC. I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTE and copied it to DVD and did a clean installation.

After the system installed the OS and rebooted, it came up with an error advising no drive. I have my boot sequence as DVD and then HDD prior to disconnecting my HDD with Windows 7 on it. So I went in to the BIOS and there is no HDD visable at all just my DVD drive?

As advised I am new to all this and everything is so confusing.

All I would like to do is have just Ubuntu as my OS and be able to start my PC. I am currently using the disc to run Ubuntu from.

Many thanks for any help.

Best regards,
Davy

Comment: Does *Ubuntu* see the hard drive? Open up an application called gparted and see if the drive is listed as /dev/sda or something similar to that.

Comment: Hi mchid. When I load Ubuntu from the DVD, I think it is called Live, yes it see the drive and tells me it is ther. I have just plugged my Windows 7 Drive back in now and again it does not even see the drive. I will try the gparted thing :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to know if the hard drive is listed in gparted. If the hard drive is listed in gparted, that means Ubuntu can see the hard drive when you are logged into a live session. Thanks.

Comment: Hiya, yes it is there :  Partition: /dev/sda1    File Sytem: ext4    Size: 924.01gb    Used: 18.50GiB

Comment: But it also has a /dev/sda2 & /dev/sda5 ? Thanks

Comment: what are those formatted as? one of them should be for linux swap space. There should not be a partition for bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted to reformat the drive to ext4 (**YOU WILL LOSE ALL THE DATA SO BACK ANY PERSONAL STUFF UP**, although there should be no personal data because it won't boot yet).

Make sure the partition scheme is an MS dos or BIOS type partition scheme (you need an MBR!).

Create one big ext4 partition.

Repeat the installation.

Comment: mchid. Thank you for the help. I understand the format part but how do I do that? through rebooting my desktop and having the DVD go through the install again? Sorry again for my stupid questions. I also understand that I have nothing to lose as it is a new drive and all that is on there is the initial installation. Thanks again.

Comment: that's fine you've gotta learn some time. Use gparted to erase each of the individual partitions. You will be left with available space. I believe you right click on the drive and select the partition scheme either before or during the creation of of the new partition. Select the format as a primary partition, ext4.

Comment: @Davy here is a good link http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-create-partition-table

Comment: Thanks mchid. I am in gparted. clicked on /dev/sda1. then top menu: Partion and format to > ext4. Is that correct & How do I ensure it is MS dos or BIOS type? Thanks

Comment: @Davy actually here is what you want

Comment: @Davy delete /dev/sda1

Comment: @Davy then click create, and then select type primary

Comment: @Davy make sure to also delete /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda2!!!

Comment: IT won't let me delete /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda2 as there is a key next to it as though it is locked?

Comment: @Davy right click the partition and choose unmount

Comment: @Davy also, click view and then select device info. You want it to say "Partition Table: msdos" about half way down the  list of info on the left.

Comment: Ok so I unmounted it by clicking the eject button next to the drive on the left hand side of my screen on the kinda task bar. It dos say msdos :)  But the keys are still next to /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda2 even after refreshing the devices

Comment: @Davy that works. you actually would have had to have unmounted /dev/sda5 first and then /dev/sda2. The same goes for deleting, you must delete /dev/sda5 before you will be able to delete /dev/sda2 because /dev/sda5 is a sub partition of /dev/sda2.

Comment: ok so the drive is mounted again. none of my doing.

Comment: @Davy actually, if you want to, you can create a 4GB partition first as linux swap, then use the remaining space as a primary partition ext4. You get slightly better performance this way

Comment: @Davy You should be able to unmount /dev/sda2 after you unmount /dev/sda5

Comment: sounds good mchid. But there are still the keys on there and it won't allow me to change it? how do I start from scratch without any partition and what not to be able to create the swap partion. FDisk used to do this for me back in the days on microsft lol

Comment: @Davy well, you have to unmount the all the partitions first. Also, windows doesn't use swap space.

Comment: mchid. You have been a great help. I confess. I am an idiot. so I am going to try to reinstall by restarting with the disk in the drive and that should allow me to delete any partitions and create the swap drive. I will if you will allow me to get back to you about it after I try? Thanks a million.

Comment: @Davy I believe you can run the command, `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda1` to make one big partition and then you can do the installation as normal from there. Make sure to remove the DVD before you try to boot up after installation also.

Comment: @Davy, sure, just post any errors.

Comment: @Davy but you would still have to delete the other two partitions first, it sounds like you have a good idea of starting over.

Comment: awesome. will try that shortly :) thanks mchid

Comment: Wow. Just deleted the swap space and now creating 1 large partition the size of the drive. Ext4 and it has a space for mount point. Am I good thus far or should I create a swap space 4000mb in size? Does it need to be primary or logical?

Comment: Also does it need to be primary or logical?

Comment: @Davy First of all, do  not save any space for booting if that's what you meant by "mount point". The only extra space you need is for swappiness. Swap space (a swap partition) is used when your ram gets full and the system will swap out cached ram to the swap partition when ram gets full. If you choose to do the install normally, it should create a swap partition automatically for you so I wouldn't worry about it. You see the system will boot from the MBR which is separate from the partitions. It seems last time that you didn't get the right info on the MBR as you should have and I'm guessing

Comment: @Davy that's why it didn't work last time for whatever reason. Oh yeah and of course, swap space is extra space (I think I wrote space instead of extra space above). Don't worry about it too much, it sounds good to me. If you do the install and it doesn't work again, we could always try manually writing grub (the bootloader) to the MBR from a live session. Please post any errors and good luck.

Comment: Thanks. And I did create a swap space of 4gb and the rest of the 1tb as the drive but after the istalling it still says reboot and select a proper boot device. I am about to pull out my hair. Lol. Maybe I will try it again with fresh eyes tomorrow.

Comment: @Davy try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26403/discussion-on-answer-by-mchid-clean-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-2-lts-on-pc-will-no).